# The Expanding & Folding of the information related to a checkbox isn't working in drupal 7.34

Tags: 7, forms

I am using Drupal-7.34, and after enabling the following modules:

- Admin-Menu.
- Ctools.
- IMCE.
- IMCE Wysiwyg Bridge.
- insert.
- jquery-Update.
- Libraries.
- Link.
- Pathauto.
- Token.
- Views.
- Wysiwyg.
- Webform.

I got a problem about the "Expanding & Folding of the information related to a check box"

**For Example:**
After enabling all the modules listed above, when I enter into the configuration of the "View UI" Module and try to "Add a view"; And after checking/unchecking the check boxes of "Description", "Create a Page View" or "Create a Block View", the information related to these check boxes is not expanded or folded. (Just the mark of checking/unchecking will appear/disappear and nothing else happen.

Note that before enabling the following modules listed above, this problem didn't appear and everything was great...

**any help will be appreciated, Thank you in advance.**

IN THE IMAGE BELOW, YOU CAN NOTICE HOT THE DESCRIPTION CHECK BOX IS CHECKED BUT THE TEXT BOX TO WRITE A DESCRIPTION ISN'T APPEAR AND ALSO HOW THE CREATE A PAGE CHECK BOX IS UNCHECKED BUT ALL THE INFORMATION RELATED TO IT STILL APPEARED AND DIDN'T DISAPPEAR OR FOLD...

[image: Screenshot About the Problem]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue back in August. It was the jQuery update module that was the problem.  The configuration at this link finally worked for me: https://www.drupal.org/node/1810656#comment-8677587

Comment: Thank you very much RoloDMonkey for your quick help. Actually, i resolved the question by my own side and it works fine for me until now... When you face the problem sited above in the question.
**Main Problem:** The problem come from the "Jquery Update" Module.

**To Solve the Problem:** 1) Disable the "Jquery Update" Module.
                                 or
                          2) Go to the "Configuration" of the                "Jquery Update" Module and then 
                      change the "Default jQuery Version" to "Default (Provided by drupal)" .